# Spring integration http testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I am trying to test the routing I have configured on my http inbound channel. The test is working if I have the following test code:

```
@Test
public void success() throws JsonProcessingException, ServletException, IOException, Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(createRequest());

    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    request.setMethod("POST");
    request.setRequestURI("/service/agent/onbreak");
    request.setContent(json.getBytes());
    request.setContentType("application/json");

    Map<String, String> pathVars = new AntPathMatcher().extractUriTemplateVariables(
            "/service/agent/{function}", "/service/agent/onbreak");
    request.setAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE, pathVars);

    MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

    inboundGateway.handleRequest(request, response);

    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), response.getStatus());

    verify(mockAgentService, times(1)).onBreak(any(AgentOnBreakRequest.class));
}
```

My issue with the above method is that I need to apply set the pathVars on the mock request. I have been trying unsuccessfully to use the MockMvc classes. I was at the point where I could submit the json payload successfully however it is not being passed on to the http inbound channel adapter.

Spring config:

```
<int-http:inbound-channel-adapter channel="http.incoming.agent.request.channel" supported-methods="POST"
                                  path="service/agent/{function}">
    <int-http:header name="function" expression="#pathVariables.function"/>
</int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:router input-channel="http.incoming.agent.request.channel" expression="headers.function">
    <int:mapping value="onbreak" channel="asl.agent.convert.on.break" />
</int:router>

<int:json-to-object-transformer input-channel="asl.agent.convert.on.break"
                                output-channel="asl.agent.request.channel" 
                                type="agent.dto.AgentOnBreakRequest"/>

<int:payload-type-router input-channel="asl.agent.request.channel">
    <int:mapping channel="request.asl.agent.on.break" type="com.mhgad.za.vitel.server.agent.dto.AgentOnBreakRequest"/>
</int:payload-type-router>

<int:service-activator input-channel="request.asl.agent.on.break" output-channel="asl.agent.response.channel"
                       ref="agentService" method="onBreak" />

<bean id="agentService" class="service.agent.impl.AgentServiceImpl"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler default-servlet-name="AgentService"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/*" view-name="initialView" />
```

Test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("test/resources/webapp")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/agent-integration.xml", "classpath:spring/agent-beans.xml",
"classpath:spring/test-router-config.xml"})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class AgentOnBreakRouteTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webCtx;

    @Test
    public void successful() throws JsonProcessingException, Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(createRequest());

        MockMvc mvc = webAppContextSetup(webCtx).build();
        mvc.perform(post("service/agent/onbreak").content(json)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>aslAgentGateway</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>aslAgentGateway</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

log:

```
08:55:25.121 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name '' processing POST request for [service/agent/onbreak]
08:55:25.124 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path service/agent/onbreak
08:55:25.124 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [service/agent/onbreak]
08:55:25.124 [main] DEBUG o.s.i.h.i.IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path service/agent/onbreak
08:55:25.125 [main] DEBUG o.s.i.h.i.IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [service/agent/onbreak]
08:55:25.125 [main] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [service/agent/onbreak] in DispatcherServlet with name ''
08:55:25.126 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Judging from the log, the dispatcher cannot route the request to the inbound channel. Can anyone advise me on how to accomplish this? I have looked through various examples and postings but have come up short so far.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why your `web.xml` doesn't have `DispatcherServlet` declaration? BTW does it work as regular web application on the normal servlet container?

Comment: The test web.xml is a subset of the 1 I am deployed with where I have another path using the DispatcherServlet.

Comment: The test web.xml is a subset of the 1 I am deployed with where I have another path using the DispatcherServlet. Is it advisable to to prefer the DispatcherServlet?

Comment: To be honest I'm not familiar with MockMvc, so I don't know what to say on the matter. Even if I am an author of that `IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping`, there was no reasons for me to test it with MockMvc. From other side, bear in mind that `AbstractHandlerMethodMapping` has `detectHandlerMethodsInAncestorContexts = false`. That means that only the current application context is scanned for the `RequestMapping`. So, maybe your `@ContextConfiguration` classes aren't visible for that `WebApplicationContext`?

Comment: My experience with MockMvc is also negligible. Basically I am just trying to confirm the SpEL expressions are correct as well, without having to hard code the values in the servlet request attribute. Tho the tests will pickup a problem if the configuration changes. I'll use the first method where is does successful route to the service bean.